# How to install android studio created app on mobile without connecting it to system

Tags: android, mobile, apk

I want to copy apk file from android studio project on my mobile without connecting it to any machine.
what is path of that apk file.

Answer (score 0):

You can send it to your mobile via **emailing** and then install it by **clicking** the attachment.

PS: You need your developer options in **enabled** mode and your install app from **un-trusted source** must be **enable** as well.

PSS: Please google properly before asking question.